# Flink - How to find all classes under a java package in flink sinkfunction

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-flink, flink-streaming

How to find all classes under a java package in flink sinkfunction? I get nothing when run these code in my SinkFunction. see follow code

```
public Set<Class> findAllClassesUsingClassLoader(String packageName) {
    InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
      .getResourceAsStream(packageName.replaceAll("[.]", "/"));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    return reader.lines()
      .filter(line -> line.endsWith(".class"))
      .map(line -> getClass(line, packageName))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private Class getClass(String className, String packageName) {
    try {
        return Class.forName(packageName + "."
          + className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf('.')));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle the exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Explain what is your problem and what you want to achieve